# c# detection of mouse direction from last motion?

Tags: c#, mouseevent

How can I detect mouse's direction from last pixel?

For example my mouse at 100;100. 
When I moved it 98;100 a bool named *Left* must be true.
And after, when I moved it 99 *Right* must be true,Left false indeed.

When there is no move,both are *false*.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Well that seems like a good way to go, got any code?

Comment: As different from that draft, yes. I got mouse positions while it's in a panel and I want that panel to not overflow another, but code is different, so i didn't put here.

Comment: Are you using winforms, or WPF or what?

Comment: I'm using winforms 4.0 on c#.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assume You Save your previous position in Point Variable, caller PrevPoint. Assume Present Mouse position is stored in Point called PresentPoint. Then the following will Give You desired results:

```
 int DiffX = (PresentPoint.X - PrevPoint.X);
 bool Left =  DiffX < 0;
 bool Right = DiffX > 0;
 // The same for Vertical direction, if Y goes bottom up
 int DiffY = (PresentPoint.Y - PrevPoint.Y);
 bool Up   = DiffY > 0;
 bool Down = DiffY < 0;
```

Comment: Before somebody says anything, I do not just use Right = !Left, because there might be situations, when no changes occur, then both Right and Left would be false.

Comment: I think that question is asking how to query the most position

Comment: I asked this question for this: I have a panel in another panel. That small panel is moving by the mouse. The move functions are vertical and horizontal. I have bounded the move if small's left equals the bigger's and small's right equals the bigger's. But when made this, if I limit the move for left, the function limits automatically limit the move for right, I wanted to overcome this. And it seems to be a reliable answer but I must think on this, thank you both.